# grep return line but exclude pattern

Tags: bash, grep, find

I am looking for a way to generate a directory from a filename without the 
version part of it. I need to set this new directory as a variable, so that I can extract, chmod symlink and more.

```
find *.jar | grep -Ei "*-[0-9]."
/test/gb0100-sting-junit5-1.5.0.0.jar
```

I just need the gb0100-sting-junit5 part.

I know I can filter just the Version Part but I don't know how to regex the part before

```
grep -Po "-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the more general case, when version number may be be more than one digit, or when the number of numeric groups in the version can be more or less than 4, consider the following options:

Using bash pattern, eliminate trailing sequence of digits/dot and jar suffix

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *.jar ; do
    printf '%s\n' "${file%%-+([0-9.]).jar}"
done
```

Sometimes, it's easier to use the more powerful REGEX, which can be used to define  rules that reject combinations like '5..2.jar', etc. Also, it is usually easier to make REGEX rules than pattern rules.

```
for file in *.jar ; do
   [[ "$file" =~ ^(.*)-+([0-9])(\.[0-9]+)*.jar$ ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

For large number of files, should also consider sed, using the same REGEX. It is usually more efficient, and can be used to create more complex command with xargs, etc.

```
ls *.jar | sed -E -e 's/^(.*)-+([0-9])(\.[0-9]+)*.jar$/\1/'
```

Comment: sed did the trick for me. You are right. Forgot to mention that there are multiple files that get deployed at once. 
Thank you very much for ur support!